# semantic-ui search from server response does not work

Tags: php, jquery, semantic-ui

I tried to use semantic-ui search part and get response from server. When i tried the following code:

```
 $('.ui.search').search({
      apiSettings: {
          url: '/tsmon-dev/zzz.php',
        },
        type: 'category'
    });
 });
```

it works, but there are two problems. First, whatever i type, it shows all the results as hint rather than results including what i type. Second, i cannot limit max results by this. So i tried following, which add some code:

```
$('.ui.search').search({
      apiSettings: {
          url: '/tsmon-dev/zzz.php',
       onResponse: function(serverResponse) {
          alert('a');
        var
            response = {
                results: {}
            }
        ;
        console.log('!');
        console.log(serverResponse);
        //translate Server API response to work with search
        $.each(serverResponse.subtopics, function(index, subtopic) {
            var
                result = subtopic.result || 'Unknown',
                maxResults = 8
            ;

            if(response.results[result] === undefined) {
                response.results[result] = {
                    name: result,
                    results: []
                };
            }
            //add result to category
            response.results[result].results.push({
                title: subtopic.name,
                url: subtopic.html_url

            });
        });
        return response;
    },
        },
        type: 'category'
    });
```

However, after i use this, it does notwork. I do not know, so how to make it work?  Or any other ways to limit the max results as hint in PHP?  Thank you so much!